# NFC programming without NFC chip in Tablets / Phones?

Tags: android, nfc

A short question but can't find no confirmation on other Forums. Hopefully someone knows on stackoverflow.

**QUESTION:** if I have a *tablet that does not have a NFC chip* inside, but I **use an external NFC reader** (With Android Support Library) connected to the tablet - can I still **manipulate the data** (read / write) from the NFC card (tapped on the external NFC reader) through my Application on Tablet ?

To me it seems possible, since the NFC reader has to do the reading and then I communicate with the reader through my Application. Since the reader supports Android Library, it should work. Please confirm.

Comment: Why don't you simply try it, if you already have everything necessary?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The thing is, I posses neither of those. I'm in process of ordering it.

Comment: I see - I misunderstood your post. I have no explicit experience here, but if it supports the android support library, I'm not exactly sure what more confirmation you'll be able to find.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. The ACR 122U download includes an Android SDK. I have published an Android util demonstrating some rudimentary functionality in Google play - [ACR 122 USB NFC Reader Utils](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skjolberg.acr122u). I have also other apps for some of the other ACS readers, and a (paid) app aimed at developers doing proof of concept apps.